# Extract trajectory/ground truth from video

Tags: matlab, video, extract, tracking, motion

Is there a software/toolbox in which I can extract the mobile robot trajectory from video recordings? My algorithm uses mobile robot to track a U-shaped trajectory, and I would like to mark/extract that trajectory from video. I used a stationary camera observing the robot motion in indoor environment. I would prefer if there is a Matlab toolbox available, but any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In r2012b, use a [VideoReader](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/index.html) to iterate through the movie, one frame at a time. For older versions of Matlab, use the [aviread()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2009b/techdoc/ref/aviread.html) function.

For each frame, call [ginput()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) to collect graphical input from the user.

```
myVideo = VideoReader('myRobotVideo.avi');
n = myVideo.NumberOfFrames;
x = nan(n,1);
y = nan(n,1);
for i = 1:n
  img = read(myVideo,i);
  imshow(img);
  [x(i),y(i)] = ginput();
end
disp([x,y])
```

This is a convenient technique for quickly annotating computer vision ground truth.

Alternatively, if you don't have the toolbox, you can use an open source tool such as [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert the video as a series of .png images, and then iterate through these using the built-in `imread()` function.